# What is alternative of added in Java 9 `Matcher#replaceAll(Function)` for earlier versions of Java?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I'm trying to find an alternative to the functional interface used in my code below.
It's working on my local machine but when I try to run it on my server which doesn't support java 9 , it won't compile.
Any thoughts on how to re-implement the following without using functional interface ?

```
public class Brackets {
    Pattern parentheses = Pattern.compile(
            "\\([\\p{InARABIC}\\s\\$]+\\)|\\([\\p{InBasic_Latin}\\s\\$]+\\)|\\)([\\p{InARABIC}\\s]+)\\(",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    @Override

    public String replace(String text) {
        String newText;

        Matcher parenthesesMatcher = parentheses.matcher(text);
            newText = parenthesesMatcher.replaceAll(match -> {
                if (parenthesesMatcher.group(1) == null) {
                    return Matcher.quoteReplacement(parenthesesMatcher.group());
                } else {
                    return Matcher.quoteReplacement("(" + match.group(1) + ")");
                }
            });

}
```

Eg :
 
Input
 
-----------
 
Output

```
)أ(
)السلام(
هذا مجرد ) مثال ( .. طبعا
-----------
(أ)
(السلام)
هذا مجرد ( مثال ) .. طبعا
```

Comment: what does your server support?

Comment: It supports java 8 , however I think my code runs on java 9 or higher

Comment: Why is there `@Override` annotation in the code you posted? Your class `Brackets` extends class `java.lang.Object` and doesn't implement any interfaces and there is no `replace()` method in class `Object`. Also, perhaps you can post the compile errors you are getting?

Comment: I had to delete some of my code to simplify it to solve the problem of the functional interface that my server doesn't support

Comment: Can You post some input strings and expected output?

Answer (score 3):

[`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) was added in Java 9 as shorter version of

```
StringBuffer sb = new StrinbBuffer(); 
while(matcher.find()){ 
    String replacement = /*replacement based on current match*/
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement); 
} 
matcher.appendTail(sb); 
String replacementResult = sb.toString();
```

So as you see above template only needs way to decide what should be replacement based on current match, in other words Function which would change `currenMatch` -> `replacement`.

So "old way" of your code could look like:

```
@Override
public String replace(String text) {

    Matcher m = parentheses.matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()){
        if (m.group(1) == null) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group()));
        } else {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement("(" + m.group(1) + ")"));
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `StringBuffer` is used only in this method so You can replace it with `StringBuilder` for better performance.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks, if I will be applying this code to parentheses () , Brackets[] and curly braces {} , I'll be duplicating three times the code where every time I'll be correcting either )( to () or/and ][ to [] etc .. , I won't get 3 times the text as output ? https://ideone.com/c8Q9MT

Comment: @zolv `appendReplacement` which accepts `StringBuilder` was added in Java 9, but since OP can't use `replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)` that suggests code is executed on earlier versions of Java so I can't use `StringBuilder` here, and unfortunately must stick with `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @Slach You can create *one* regex which is searching for either `()` or `[]` or `{}` and then create replacement based on what was found (just see if match starts with `(` or `[` or `{`).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `replaceAll` method at this line:

```
newText = parenthesesMatcher.replaceAll(match -> {
```

In Java 8 replaceAll can accept only a `String` argument while in Java 9, this method has been overloaded with another version which also accepts a `Function<MatchResult, String> replacer`. So, you will have to downgrade your code in order to run it in Java 8.